# How to debug a webview in react native

Tags: react-native-ios

We are using a react native webview. when we run the app in ios, app is running and webview is also loading the given URL. There is some issue in the html and i want to debug it. I'm not able to to debug it. Any idea/reference regarding the same would be helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Enable "Web Inspector" from the iOS simulator. In iOS 11, that's:

Settings -> Safari -> Advanced -> Web Inspector

2. Open Safari on your computer, and enable Developer options:

Safari -> Preferences -> Advanced -> Show develop menu in menu bar

3. Open your app in the iOS simulator, and navigate to whichever view contains a WebView.
4. Open the HTML page:

[image: I have multiple webviews mounted, so there's two "index.html" files]

If you don't see your simulator in the develop menu, try restarting the simulator (Hardware -> Restart).