# Debug webview in react native IOS from Windows computer

Tags: ios, windows, react-native, react-native-ios

I've been developing a react native application with Expo that should work both on Android and iOS.

I've an iPhone in hands and use an android simulador to check how things are going with the Android version of the app, as there are multiple times, as everyone developing on react-native knows, you encounter difference on those.

My problem now is that I have some javascript code running on a WebView which I found out I can debug on the android using Google Chrome Dev Tools but for the iPhone side of things, the only thing I found was Safari equivalent of Google Chrome Dev Tools which only works on a Mac ([How to debug a webview in react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47991959/how-to-debug-a-webview-in-react-native)).

And to clarify why this is important to me, right now, I got that webview code working on android but that same code doesn't work on iPhone.

Is there another alternative to debug javascript code inside react-native web view on iOS?

Comment: Does the protocol have a security layer? let's say `https` instead of `http`

Comment: Ended up finding what was the error with my code, but this problem stands. Haven't found anyway to debug the code inside the WebView, what happened in my case was that the problem was prior to the WebView code being ran.